# How to handle multiple heterogeneous inputs with Logstash?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, graylog2

Let's say you have 2 very different types of logs such as technical and business logs and you want:

- raw technical logs be routed towards a graylog2 server using a `gelf` output,
- json business logs be stored into an elasticsearch cluster using the dedicated `elasticsearch_http` output.

I know that with `Syslog-NG` for instance, the configuration file allow to define several distinct inputs which can then be processed separately before being dispatched; what `Logstash` seems unable to do. Even if one instance can be initiated with two specific configuration files, all logs take the same channel and are being applied the same processings ...

Should I run as many instances as I have different types of logs?

Comment: You should accept Ben Lim's correct answer!

Answer (score 198):

> Should I run as many instances as I have different types of logs?

No! You can only run one instance to handle different types of logs.

In the logstash configuration file, you can specific each input with different [type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-type). 
Then in the filter you can use [if](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) to distinct different processing,
and also at the output you can use "if" output to different destination.

```
input {
    file {
            type => "technical"
            path => "/home/technical/log"
    }
    file {
            type => "business"
            path => "/home/business/log"
    }
} 
filter {
    if [type] == "technical" {
            # processing .......
    }
    if [type] == "business" {
            # processing .......
    }
}
output {
    if [type] == "technical" {
            # output to gelf
    }
    if [type] == "business" {
            # output to elasticsearch
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: You can also use the `type` attribute (with the same `type => "value"` syntax) in the filter and output definitions which should cut down on the extra formatting within the config file a bit.  Example: https://gist.github.com/fairchild/3030472 Per documentation: Add a 'type' field to all events handled by this input.

Types are used mainly for filter activation.

The type is stored as part of the event itself, so you can also use the type to search for it in the web interface.

Comment: Well, it looks like what Ben provided is actually the new way to do this.  When I used `type => "value"` in an output, I got the following message displayed: "You are using a deprecated config setting "type" set in stdout. Deprecated settings will continue to work, but are scheduled for removal from logstash in the future. You can achieve this same behavior with the new conditionals, like: `if [type] == "sometype" { stdout { ... } }`."  I retract my previous comment. :)

Comment: Note that the `type` attribute won't apply if there's already a type field from the input. This is a special attribute that doesn't override and it's documented. I opened a ticket in Elastic and they recommended me to use `tags` or `add_field` instead of `type`

Comment: @BornToCode, I don't quite understand. Are you saying there is something wrong with Ben's code? Or that it wouldn't work if the log paths were the same file? What's the scenario where it doesn't work?

Comment: @BenWheeler - I'm saying that in a scenario where there's already a "type" field (e.g. log came from filebeat service and filebeat was defined to add a custom field "type" with some value) then Ben's code won't work, because he checks `if [type] == "technical"` and that would never be true because type's value will always be the value that existed there before logstash came to play.

Comment: @BenLim The OP did not accept your answer but I found it most helpful and up-voted you.

Comment: Thank you. Although everyone says it's helpful but the OP do not want to accept my answer. lolx

Answer (score 18):

I used tags for multiple file input:

```
input {
    file {
        type => "java"
        path => "/usr/aaa/logs/stdout.log"
        codec => multiline {
            ...
        },
        tags => ["aaa"]
    }

    file {
        type => "java"
        path => "/usr/bbb/logs/stdout.log"
        codec => multiline {
                ...
        }
        tags => ["bbb"]
    }
}
output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    if "aaa" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["192.168.100.211:9200"]
            index => "aaa"
            document_type => "aaa-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }

    if "bbb" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["192.168.100.211:9200"]
            index => "bbb"
            document_type => "bbb-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer: it allows multiple filebeat inputs in logstash. In such cases, the "type" property is set to "log" and cannot be modified.

Comment: But isn't this overwriting tags with the last tag (bbb)?
And then again, in the if statememt, if the tags were an array or single string, then both IF's would work. So logically this is incorrect, but maybe logstash has a different logic inside if's

Answer (score 0):

I think logstash can't read more than 2 files in Input section . try the below

```
input {
    file {
            type => "technical"
            path => "/home/technical/log"
    }
    file {
            type => "business"
            path => "/home/business/log"
    }
 file {
            type => "business1"
            path => "/home/business/log1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, run into same 'issue'