# Track data from multiple log files using Logstash and Elasticsearch and mapping in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am using `filebeat` to send multiple files to `Logstash` but I am not able to map which file has which status So what are the possible ways to track mapped data for each log file.

Comment: What do you mean by `I am not able to map which file has which status` ? Are you indexing multiple file into single elasticsearch index and type?

Comment: yes index is same for all files

Comment: for each file there  is id name and status which will be use as filter

Comment: I think you should index each log file in separate type.

Comment: Can you share your logstash and filebeat conf file? Please refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330541/how-to-handle-multiple-heterogeneous-inputs-with-logstash) it will give you idea how to handle multiple files, though solution for file input. we have similar option in filebeat too.

Comment: but i need to make final charts based on all log files data in kibana

Comment: All log files will be store in same index but in different type.  I don't think so you will face any problem while creation of the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `source` field which is coming from filebeat to filter your logs. Please check [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/exported-fields-log.html#exported-fields-log) for more information.

> The file from which the line was read. This field contains the full path to the file. For example: /var/log/system.log.

You can give not_analyzed property for this field to filter more effectively.