# How can I create JSON format log when entering into Elasticsearch by logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

i been told that, by using logstash pipeline i can re-create a log format(i.e JSON) when entering into elasticsearch. but not understanding how to do it .

current LOGStash Configure ( I took bellow from Google , not for any perticular reason)

```
/etc/logstash/conf.d/metrics-pipeline.conf
```

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    client_inactivity_timeout => "3600"
  }
}




filter {
    if [message] =~ />/ {
        dissect {
            mapping => {
                "message" => "%{start_of_message}>%{content}"
            }
        }

        kv {
            source => "content"
            value_split => ":"
            field_split => ","
            trim_key => "\[\]"
            trim_value => "\[\]"
            target => "message"
        }

        mutate {
            remove_field => ["content","start_of_message"]
        }
    }
}



filter {
  if [system][process] {
    if [system][process][cmdline] {
      grok {
        match => {
          "[system][process][cmdline]" => "^%{PATH:[system][process][cmdline_path]}"
        }
        remove_field => "[system][process][cmdline]"
      }
    }
  }

 grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }

}



output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "1.2.1.1:9200"
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

I have couple of log file located at

/root/logs/File.log
/root/logs/File2.log

the Log format there is :

```
08:26:51,753 DEBUG [ABC] (default-threads - 78) (1.2.3.4)(368)>[TIMESTAMP:Wed Sep 11 08:26:51 UTC 2019],[IMEI:03537],[COMMAND:INFO],[GPS STATUS:true],[INFO:true],[SIGNAL:false],[ENGINE:0],[DOOR:0],[LON:90.43],[LAT:23],[SPEED:0.0],[HEADING:192.0],[BATTERY:100.0%],[CHARGING:1],[O&E:CONNECTED],[GSM_SIGNAL:100],[GPS_SATS:5],[GPS POS:true],[FUEL:0.0V/0.0%],[ALARM:NONE][SERIAL:01EE]
```

in Kibana by default it shows like ethis

https://imgshare.io/image/stackflow.I0u7S
https://imgshare.io/image/jsonlog.IHQhp

```
 "message": "21:33:42,004 DEBUG [LOG] (default-threads - 100) (1.2.3.4)(410)>[TIMESTAMP:Sat Sep 07 21:33:42 UTC 2019],[TEST:123456],[CMD:INFO],[STATUS:true],[INFO:true],[SIGNAL:false],[ABC:0],[DEF:0],[GHK:1111],[SERIAL:0006]"
```

but i want to get it like bellow :-

```
"message": {
      "TIMESTAMP": "Sat Sep 07 21:33:42 UTC 2019",
      "TEST": "123456",
      "CMD":INFO,
      "STATUS":true,
      "INFO":true,
      "SIGNAL":false,
      "ABC":0,
      "DEF":0,
      "GHK":0,
      "GHK":1111
    }
```

Can this be done ? if yes how ? 
Thanks

Comment: Yes it can be done. The easiest way would be to apply the kv filter on the part after the >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `if [message] =~ />/`, the filters will only apply to messages containing a `>`. The dissect filter will split the message between the `>`. The kv filter will apply a key-value transformation on the second part of the message, removing the `[]`. The mutate.remove_field remove any extra field.

```
filter {
    if [message] =~ />/ {
        dissect {
            mapping => {
                "message" => "%{start_of_message}>%{content}"
            }
        }

        kv {
            source => "content"
            value_split => ":"
            field_split => ","
            trim_key => "\[\]"
            trim_value => "\[\]"
            target => "message"
        }

        mutate {
            remove_field => ["content","start_of_message"]
        }
    }
}
```

Result, using the provided log line:

```
{
  "@version": "1",
  "host": "YOUR_MACHINE_NAME",
  "message": {
    "DEF": "0",
    "TIMESTAMP": "Sat Sep 07 21:33:42 UTC 2019",
    "TEST": "123456",
    "CMD": "INFO",
    "SERIAL": "0006]\r",
    "GHK": "1111",
    "INFO": "true",
    "STATUS": "true",
    "ABC": "0",
    "SIGNAL": "false"
  },
  "@timestamp": "2019-09-10T09:21:16.422Z"
}
```

In addition to doing the filtering with `if [message] =~ />/`, you can also do the comparison on the `path` field, which is set by the file input plugin. Also if you have multiple file inputs, you can set the `type` field and use this one, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20562031/6113627.

Comment: Hi Thanks, but i get this error in logstatsh
Sep 10 14:03:00 kibana logstash[19858]: [2019-09-10T16:03:00,262][WARN ][org.logstash.dissect.Dissector] Dissector mapping, pattern not found {"field"=>"message", "pattern"=>"%{start_of_message}>%{content}",

Comment: It means that this message didn't contain a `>`. If you are also receiving messages that don't contains `>`, you'd have to deal with them, either dropping them or not parsing them with the filter I wrote above.

Comment: Add those messages to your question, with what you want to do with them and I'll expand my answer.

Comment: Thanks @baudsp,  i am pushing different type of log file  so each log file has different type of structure , it could be that reason, is there anyway to apply filter only for a specifiq log file ?

Comment: Yes. I'll update my answer with something to this effect.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late reply, please see this screen shot, this is the log i get into kibana 
https://imgshare.io/image/stackflow.I0u7S
with your latest changes, kibana does not process anything, i gave you the screen shot to understand how we getting, Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you add to your question the configuration you're using and any logstash logs, please? I've taken a look to your screenshot, but I don't have any idea on what's the issue.

Comment: thanks, yes, i have edited the my question with more info as you requested, also see the existing kibana format for raw log and json
https://imgshare.io/image/stackflow.I0u7S
https://imgshare.io/image/jsonlog.IHQhp

Comment: From the logstash configuration you've posted, you're not using the solution I provided.

Comment: yes, when i put that, Logstash does not show any logs at all, 
shall i remove my config and just put your one ?

Comment: i edited the question with your filter, but with this logs does not enter into kibana