# Clarification on Index/Index Pattern Creation Logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-forwarder

Followed this Elastic link: [Parsing your first logs with logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html)

works great and I can use discover to see the Apache logs in Kibana. Yay!

So now, I have my Palo FW logs and have adjusted the Filebeat file from the tutorial as such:

```
paths:
- /var/log/logstash/logstash-tutorial.log
- /var/log/PaloaltoFW/PA-220-Dev.log
```

And I get an ERROR in Kibana on Index Patterns for filebeat-*, which rectifies if I switch to the one from the tutorial logstash-%DATE-00001 as default !

pipelines.yml

```
- pipeline.id: sample
path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/first-pipeline.conf"

- pipeline.id: main
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/PaloFW-pipeline.conf"

- pipeline.id: rsyslog
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/rsyslog.conf"
```

Also I do remove the registry files from filebeat.

My PaloFW-pipeline.conf:

```
# The # character at the beginning of a line indicates a comment. Use
# comments to describe your configuration.
input {
beats {
port => "5044"
type => "syslog"
}
}
# The filter part of this file is commented out to indicate that it is
# optional.
filter {
if [type] == "syslog" {
grok {
match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
}
date {
match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
}
}
kv {}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => [ "10.10.69.20:9200" ]
}
}
```

I can now see the logs in Kibana, but had to switch to my default Index and the filebeat-* still gets the error at the beginning of post. Ideally I want the parse the tutorial.log and my firewall.log on the logstash server and have them show up as seperate indicies and index patterns...once I do that I will move on to other use cases.

So they load into the index from the tutorial logstash-%DATE%-0001 and I can see them, my filters could be better. But I need to sort out how indexes work and if I can use filebeat for more than 1 .log and create more than 1 index.

Many thanks community for any clarification!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20562031/6113627

Comment: But where does identify the automic index creation for that log file being processed? 
'input {
    file {
            type => "technical"
            path => "/home/technical/log"
    }
    file {
            type => "business"
            path => "/home/business/log"
    }
} 
filter {
    if [type] == "technical" {
            # processing .......
    }
    if [type] == "business" {
            # processing .......
    }
}
output {
    if [type] == "technical" {
            # output to gelf
    }
    if [type] == "business" {
            # output to elasticsearch
  '

Comment: By default, the elasticsearch logstash output plugin uses the `logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}` index (so one index per day) (from the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index))